# Why is there this big gray block at the bottom?

Tags: html, css, drupal

At http://www.raptorshop.com, there is a gigantic big gray block at the bottom.

What would cause this? Is it something in Drupal, or something just in the plain CSS that I am not noticing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's plain CSS. In `gray.css`, the `html` element's background color is set to `#343434`, which is that gray you're seeing. Change it to `#5C4033` if you want the brown.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `background: #343434;` in html element on **gray.css** file.

Answer (score 1):

its caused by the CSS

```
html {
  background: #343434;
}
```

in gray.css

Answer (score 1):

The color is originated at [gray.css](http://www.raptorshop.com/themes/acquia_prosper/design_packs/gray/gray.css), `html{background:#343434}`.

The body won't take the full height, unless you define the size on the `html` and `body` tag using the CSS below. Hence, the grey background is not visible (through scrolling) when you shrink your window.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The block is actually your footer-wrapper and footer-message-wrapper divs. You can change their color in the way described, or by making a new rule for the footer divs. I recommend you download Firebug. It is a firefox add-on which allows you to right click on an element in an HTML page and view all kinds of info about it, including the html and the whole cascade of styles that are in effect. You can type changes in the Firebug window and see what they will do in real time! I used it on your page and located the relevant html and css in ~10 seconds.